# Is it bad practice to require nested JSON data, on my API endpoints?

Tags: api, api-design

I've made an endpoint for creating events: `POST /events/new`

The request should have JSON data on the body. This is the JSON structure that is required for creating a new event:

```
{
    "label": "my first event",
    "description": "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
    "meta": {
        "status": "draft",
        "isOnline": true,
        "visibility": "visible",
        "customID": "my-first-event",
        "tags": ["foo", "bar"],
        "categories": ["concert", "sports"]
    }
}
```

My problem being: I don't think I've ever seen services requiring nested properties (like in `meta.status`). Is it a bad practice?

I'm doing it like that because it's more organized.

Comment: `I don't think I've ever seen services requiring nested properties`. How many services have you seen in your career? Services developer by others than you I mean.

Comment: @Laiv I work with consuming APIs a lot, actually. They always require flat objects.

Comment: The answer to the question is a big *no, it's not bad practice*. You can not measure the correctness of your decisions comparing yourself with others. Your project, your needs. Or the other way around: _you don't know if they are wrong or why they "all" made response flat maps_. Right? In any case, if we are speaking about REST, remeber that you are giving "representations" of real assets. If assets have "meta-data" and you need to share that information, then do it. The complexity of the representation is a technical decision.

Comment: @Laiv this seems to me the start of a good answer… why not go the extra mile ;-)

Comment: That’s not nested.

Answer (score 2):

No, I think this is fine.

The object is still flat, it just has namespaces.

Where it might be "bad" though is if you have a collection of child objects

```
{
   "name": "A",
   "children" : [
     { "name":"B"},....
    ]
}
```

Now if you are posting this to a "resource" style endpoint you have an open question about whether you can update/change the child objects without sending the entire object.

Not a massive issue, but perhaps something to be avoided if you don't have to go that route.

Comment: You made a good point. However, the update/change/create input is not forced to match 1:1 the GET representation. When you add a new comment in someone else' Facebook you add text only, but when you retrieve comments by [API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v15.0/comment) you get many more data. Most is meta-data.